# Rails: View javascript object's attributes in browser's console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari, console, coffeescript

I have created a variable in CoffeeScript and can verify that it logs as 'object' in the browser's console:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee
myvar =
  name: "Test"
  valid: false

jQuery ->
  console.log(myvar)
```

console output:

```
  Object
    name: "Test"
    valid: false
    __proto__: Object
```

So browser knows about the object but how can I manually dump it's values from the console (>) prompt. I'm using Safari at the moment but can switch if it's not possible w/Safari.

Comment: In FF, IE or Chrome (Safari is probably the same, but I've never used its debug tools so I'm not sure) if it's a global variable you can just type `myvar` into the console and it will show the content of the variable. (Obviously if it's a local variable the variable is only available while the function is running or if captured in a closure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript wraps your code in a function to avoid side effects between different libraries.

For example:

```
alert('hello!')
```

becomes

```
(function() {
  alert('hello!');
}).call(this);
```

This means that any variables you declare are not in the global scope, so you can't access them from the console. To explicitly attach your variables to the global scope, assign them to the `window` object:

```
window.myvar =
  name: "Test"
  valid: false
```

Comment: ah ha!!! this works. and from console I don't need `window.myvar` to access the variable; i only need `myvar`. thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. JavaScript from a browser scopes everything to `window`, so typing `myvar` is like typing `window.myvar`. Ruby does a similar thing with the [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html) module, which is what makes stuff like `require` and `puts` work.